# How can I combine multiple columns into a single column and create another column indicating the source?

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to turn a table that looks like this:

| record_id | height_1 | height_1_v1 | height_1_v1_v1 | weight_1 | weight_1_v1 | weight_1_v1_v1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | NA | NA | 5ft6in | NA | NA | 154 |
| 10 | 5ft6in | NA | NA | 152 | NA | NA |
| 10 | NA | 5ft6in | NA | NA | 153 | NA |
| 11 | NA | NA | 5.11 | NA | NA | 138 |
| 11 | NA | 5.11 | NA | NA | 131 | NA |

Into a table that looks like this:

| record_id | appt_num | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 5ft6in | 152 |
| 10 | 2 | 5ft6in | 153 |
| 10 | 3 | 5ft6in | 154 |
| 11 | 1 | 5.11 | 131 |
| 11 | 2 | 5.11 | 138 |

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

So far, I have tried pivot_longer() and gather() without success. The closest I've gotten is by using coalesce(), but I haven't been able to successfully create the appointment number (appt_num) column.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `weight` in row 3 of your expected output be `154`?

Comment: I would usually recommend against working with data formatted as in the proposed output table. You will struggle every step of the way if height, which should be numeric, has both numeric ("5.11", coerced to character) and character ("5ft6in"). Consider converting all to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial data format is awkward for many reasons ...

- awkward column names
- data values presented in reverse order
- mixed character and numeric values

... so there are quite a few steps to get where you want to be.

Here's one way to do it.  There will be others.  I've added comments at the start of each step to say what I'm doing.  if you want to investigate in detail to see what happens at each step, simply break the pipe.

```
d %>% 
  # Temporary, to allow combining into a single column
  mutate(across(starts_with("weight"), as.character)) %>% 
  # Pivot longer, discarding awkward column name suffixes
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(starts_with("height"), starts_with("weight")),
    names_pattern = "(height|weight)_(.)",
    names_to = c("name", NA)
  ) %>% 
  # Discard missing values
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  # Define appointment number
  group_by(record_id, name) %>% 
  mutate(appt_num = 1 + n() - row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(record_id, name, appt_num) %>% 
  # Pivot to required format
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value,
    id_cols = c(record_id, appt_num)
  ) %>% 
  # Convert weight back to numeric
  mutate(weight = as.numeric(weight)) %>% 
  # Remove grouping
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  record_id appt_num height weight
      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1        10        1 5ft6in    152
2        10        2 5ft6in    153
3        10        3 5ft6in    154
4        11        1 5.11      135
5        11        2 5.11      131
6        11        3 5.11      138
```

Answer (score 0):

Data frame example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(record_id=c(rep(10,3),rep(11,3)),
           height_1=c(NA_character_,NA_character_,"5ft6in",NA_character_,NA_character_,"5.11"),
           height_1_v1=c(NA_character_,"5ft6in",NA_character_,NA_character_,"5.11",NA_character_),
           height_1_v1_v1=c("5ft6in",NA_character_,NA_character_,"5.11",NA_character_,NA_character_),
           weight_1=c(NA_character_,NA_character_,"152",NA_character_,NA_character_,"135"),
           weight_1_v1=c(NA_character_,"153",NA_character_,NA_character_,"131",NA_character_),
           weight_1_v1_v1=c("154",NA_character_,NA_character_,"138",NA_character_,NA_character_))


  record_id height_1 height_1_v1 height_1_v1_v1 weight_1 weight_1_v1 weight_1_v1_v1
1        10     <NA>        <NA>         5ft6in     <NA>        <NA>            154
2        10     <NA>      5ft6in           <NA>     <NA>         153           <NA>
3        10   5ft6in        <NA>           <NA>      152        <NA>           <NA>
4        11     <NA>        <NA>           5.11     <NA>        <NA>            138
5        11     <NA>        5.11           <NA>     <NA>         131           <NA>
6        11     5.11        <NA>           <NA>      135        <NA>           <NA>
```

Transform data.frame using **pivot_longer** excluding record_id column and removing all rows with NA values. Assign values to appt_num column using **case_when** command. Remove extra text in col column and transform again the data.frame using **pivot_wider**.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(record_id),names_to="col",values_to="text") %>% filter(!is.na(text)) %>% 
  mutate(appt_num=case_when(
    grepl("1_v1_v1",col) ~ 3,
    grepl("1_v1",col) ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 1
  )) %>% mutate(col=gsub("_v1","",col)) %>% mutate(col=gsub("_1","",col)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col", values_from = "text") %>% arrange(record_id,appt_num)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  record_id appt_num height weight
      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
1        10        1 5ft6in 152   
2        10        2 5ft6in 153   
3        10        3 5ft6in 154   
4        11        1 5.11   135   
5        11        2 5.11   131   
6        11        3 5.11   138
```

**UPDATE:**

Version in case there are more columns following the same structure using **str_count** from stringr library.

```
library(stringr)

df %>% pivot_longer(-c(record_id),names_to="col",values_to="text") %>% filter(!is.na(text)) %>%
  mutate(appt_num=str_count(col,"_v1") + 1) %>%
  mutate(col=gsub("_v1","",col)) %>% mutate(col=gsub("_1","",col)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col", values_from = "text") %>% arrange(record_id,appt_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
df %>%
    split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_\\d.*"))%>%
    map_df(~coalesce(!!!.))%>%
    mutate(aptt_num = row_number(), .by=record_id)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  height record_id weight aptt_num
  <chr>      <int>  <int>    <int>
1 5ft6in        10    154        1
2 5ft6in        10    153        2
3 5ft6in        10    152        3
4 5.11          11    138        1
5 5.11          11    131        2
6 5.11          11    135        3
```

---

```
df %>%
    pack(height = starts_with('height'), weight = starts_with('weight'))%>%
    map_df(~ if(is.list(.x))coalesce(!!!.x) else .x) %>%
    mutate(apt_num = row_number(), .by = record_id)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  record_id height weight apt_num
      <int> <chr>   <int>   <int>
1        10 5ft6in    154       1
2        10 5ft6in    153       2
3        10 5ft6in    152       3
4        11 5.11      138       1
5        11 5.11      131       2
6        11 5.11      135       3
```